# Hide the referenced assemblies in the weborb console. Is this possible?

Tags: weborb

Hide the referenced assemblies in the  weborb console. Is this possible?
(weborb.dll in example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked this a year ago to the midnight coders and then it wasn't possible. I really think it still isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your referenced assemblies to the GAC. This effectively hides them from WebOrb, while permitting them to function for the deployed .dlls.

This does assume that you are permitted access to the GAC, which is not really a given.